# How is should look like push notifications request to wallet/passbook?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

I saw loot of questions about how to send push notifications to passbook, but I didn't find correct answer how should look like request. I have created passbook/wallet coupon, I have received POST request from apple with **"pushToken"** in payload and device id in URL. My coupon pass.json include next field: 

`{
   "key" : "TestDiscount",
    "label" : "Discount",
    "value" : "1%",
     "changeMessage": "Discount updated to %@."
}`

Now I try to update **Discount** value in coupon, but I don't now how :( After lot of test I did it, but I didn't so when it happend, so now I know that is possible because I did it, but don't how how I did it :) Could you explain me how is should look like push request? Do I need to use device id any where ?  So the correct payload is : `{"pushToken":"token which I received from apple","TestDiscount":"newValue"}` ? And where/when I have to use **authenticationToken** from my coupon pass.json. I'm really stuck

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an empty payload in the push request.

When the device receives it, it will call your web service, first to get the list of serials for that device that need updating, and then to download a full pkpass bundle containing new data.

If the value for your TestDiscount key is different to the value in the old pass, then the change message will show.

Comment: Dear @PassKit when I send anything (or nothing as you said) I got GET request to my server which in webServiceURL in pass.json and it's look : `/v1/devices/**DEVICE ID**/registrations/pass.test.com` and when I send answer for this request as **coupo.pkpass** I got other one POST request `POST /v1/log` which contain next :

Comment: `{"logs":["[2017-11-06 15:12:06 +0200] Get serial #s task (for device DEVICE ID, pass type pass.vinnoteka.com, last updated (null); with web service url https:\/\/f1378d11.ngrok.io) encountered error: Server response was malformed (The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.)"]} ` But when I send answer for GET request as **{"kitchenDiscount":"01%"}** nothing happens... I'm really confused

Comment: For this request you need to be sending the serial(s) of the pass(es) that need updating.  And for the next request (get latest version of the pass) you need to send the whole .pkpass bundle.  You do not send only what has changed because the new content must be signed, which is why a new bundle is sent.

Comment: Very interesting, when I change value **kitchenDiscount** in  pass.json then generate ***coupon.pkpass***  again on my Mac, I have opened it and press update button - I got push notification on my iPhone, but don't get any request to my server....

Comment: This is correct - when you replace the pass with another pass, Wallet checks the content of the new pass against the old pass and displays a local notification for any changed fields.  The push request is not a notification, it is just a trigger to tell Wallet to call your server to get a new bundle.  What you are describing is the same as what happens after Wallet has downloaded a new bundle.  The message is always local notification.

Comment: I'm really sorry, my English is not very well, so maybe that I don’t understand you well :(
 1. When device got coupon, then my server got one POST request with ** "pushToken”** and second GET - here I should return list of serials number as [“001”, ”002”] which  is the same in pass.json?   Correct ?

Comment: 2.When I  need to update some data I have to send empty push request to APNS with  "pushToken”, after that I receive GET request to my server, and here I have to get answer for this GET request as coupon.pkpass file ? Correct ?

Comment: In arcticle 2 if I send file - after that I receive POST/v1/log request which tell mee that previous GET request got error : “Server response was malformed (The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.)" But if I send json as answer I don’t get a second POST request with info about error

Comment: Number 1, no. You should not have a second get - if you do, then the get is requesting the latest version of the pass and you should send the .pkpass bundle. Number 2 - here you send the list of serials. Then you will receive another request to which you return the .pkpass bundle